# Specify VPN port in windows 10, "Edit VPN Connection"

Tags: windows, vpn, port, windows-10

It seems like i am only able to specify a hostname or an ip address as "Server name or adress", but how do I specify the port?

I was trying to separate the port with colon and comma, semicolon and space without success.

[image: from windows 10 settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the port number for the Windows built-in VPN.
The most you can do is use port-forwarding on the router.

I believe that this is possible if you use [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/)
instead of using Windows for both server and client.

Comment: Do you know if I can hack in the port in a config file or the registry for that certain connection?

Comment: I can confirm that it is possible to specify the port in OpenVPN, but I would prefer to use the VPN client that is already in the system, if possible.

Comment: As a wild idea, you might be able to change the port number of the service in the file `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\services` and reboot. The service might be `l2tp` or there might be  additional others.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN configure the Windows built-in VPN.

eg. 1.2.3.4:10443

Here are some more options for such configurations provided by Fortinet:

More options for “Server name or address” field.

(a) To use port 10443 and realm “realmname”:
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname

(b) To ignore server certificate error:
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?ignore-certificate-errors=1 , or
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?ice=1 , or
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?ice

(c) To enable pop-up to select client certificate:
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?cert=

(d) To pre-configure a client certificate:
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?cert=SubStringOfCertSubject

(e) To use PKI user (certificate user):
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?cert=&no-username-password=1 , or
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?cert=&nup=1 , or
*ServerAddress*:10443/realmname?cert=&nup

Comment: But the original post says: "I was trying to separate the port with colon and comma, semicolon and space without success." ... are you saying they're wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To specify the port just make sure it has "https://" in front of it; otherwise if you just use 1.2.3.4:1234 it doesn't work.

In my case without the port specification I didn't need the "https://" and could just enter 1.2.3.4 - but when I needed to specify the port I had to format it like this: https://1.2.3.4:1234/

Comment: I also tried this but I am getting an errror "name did not resolve" but it is working fine with other vpn client